# IF ELSE statement to run every 3 mins

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I've written the below script that checks if an item is available to "add to basket" but it just runs once until I run the script again.

How can this run every 3 minutes where if out of stock then try again in 3 minutes time. If item is in stock then end the IF Statement.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#enter link
URL = '<link>'
page = requests.get(URL)

def stock_check():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    StockQuery = soup.find("div", {"class": "add-to-basket-btn"})
print('Available')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will run until the page will have div with class add-to-basket-btn if not it will wait from 3 minutes and will try again.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

URL = '<link>'

def stock_check():
    while True:
        page = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        stockQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "add-to-basket-btn"})
        if stockQuery:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(180)
    print('Available')
stock_check()
```